# Sharepoint Online 365

Tags: sharepoint-online

How to change tamplate in Sharepoint Online 365 from Sharepoint 2013 to Sharepoint 2016? IfI choose new Site it Can only be choose 2013 not Sharepoint 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to change template to SharePoint 2016. Microsoft takes care of the upgrade when needed.

Comment: So we must wait until this pass test on Online Enviroment ? When it can be ?

Comment: Follow the Office Blog and see the upcoming changes of Office 365 https://blogs.office.com/?filter=true&filter-product=office-365

Comment: Ok so I see it will be in 2017 year.